# Using htaccess to redirect all but ONE PAGE to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I have a new website and am trying to make it https.  I am embedding a forum on one page.  The forum does not come in https !  Thus I need that one page to be served over HTTP, and not HTTPS.  I am using the standard htaccess code to force all pages to go to HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I read up on syntax a bit, but it is very complex.  I think I want to do something with the RewriteCond , because from what I read that will create an exception to the rule right below it.

My forum is on http://www.xxxx.xxx/forum.html

How to write the rule to make an exception for that page?

Comment: You know that if you don't redirect all pages, you can't use HSTS, and if you don't use HSTS, you are vulnerable to MitM/sslstrip attacks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rules in your `.htaccess` file. What this does is first check if HTTPs is not on, if not, then it will forward everything to HTTPs except for the directory `forum`. The second rule checks if HTTPs is on, if so then it will redirect `forum` back to HTTP.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(forum)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(forum)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this. If you have problems with the above rule, then you can also try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Very close!  I am testing it on http://htaccess.mwl.be/  I think that maybe there should be something at the end of line 4, behind the word forum.  Because when I test with url http://www.example.com/forum.html the test page does not return a result.  But man, you are very good!  You did something that actually works really really close, which is so much better than what I have been doing for the past 2 weeks!

Comment: Be carful testing with that website. It does not have compatibility with all features that can be used with `.htaccess`. You're better off testing via your server and changing `R=301` to `R=302` so that it is just a tmeporary redirect. If it is working for you, change it back to 301 :)

Comment: I have used 301 from the beginning (about 1 week ago).  So maybe it is best to change the forum url to forum1 or something right, and let the old url "die" ?  The site is brand new, I have not done any SEO on it, and there are no visitors yet I think, so I dont care about killing one page.

Comment: Always use `302` when testing, will avoid this sort of issue in the future :) So yes, killing the page off is the easiest option.  Although, I wouldn't name it `forum1` :P

Comment: I tried the second one, with the Rewritebase line, and it works!  After that I tried to add a second exeception for a page www.example.com/accommodations and the forum page went back to https.  Weird.  Cleaning lady is in the house now, so got to get out! Will try again tonight.  I cleared the cookies and cache of course.

Comment: Excellent! If you want to include another directory to exclude. Then you need to lay it out like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(forum|accomodations)`

Comment: WOW, it actually works!  Really amazing!  Thank you so much, you really are the guru!  Very impressive!

Comment: haha no problem @Canaldumidi :) I'm glad I could help you. Any more questions then do not hesitate to post another.

Comment: If I have a page that I want to exclude from going to HTTPS with the following URL:  www.example.com/word-word-word.html  how would I write the code for that?  Would the dashes cause a problem?  Would it be like this:  (forum|accomodations|word-word-word) ?  Thanks!  I was wondering since I was about to change the URL for the forum to a longer url with dashes.

Comment: You're exactly right @Canaldumidi. You would write it `(forum|accomodations|word-word-word)`. The dashes _shouldn't_ be an issue. But like I said, when testing these things, just change it to `R=302` so all your redirects are temporary, so if something didn't work like you expected, it is easier to fix :)